# npm i fails after updating node

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm now getting this when trying to run `npm i`:

```
    npm i
    npm ERR! path /home/ole/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/37/b4
    npm ERR! code EACCES
    npm ERR! errno -13
    npm ERR! syscall mkdir
    npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/ole/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/37/b4'
    npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/ole/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/37/b4'] {
    npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/ole/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/37/b4'] {
    npm ERR!     errno: -13,
    npm ERR!     code: 'EACCES',
    npm ERR!     syscall: 'mkdir',
    npm ERR!     path: '/home/ole/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/37/b4'
    npm ERR!   },
    npm ERR!   isOperational: true,
    npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir ' +
    npm ERR!     "'/home/ole/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/37/b4'",
    npm ERR!   errno: -13,
    npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
    npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
    npm ERR!   path: '/home/ole/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/37/b4',
    npm ERR!   parent: 'config-chain'
    npm ERR! }
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
    npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
    npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
    npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /home/ole/.npm/_logs/2019-05-14T21_15_39_992Z-debug.log
```

I've tried changing the ownership and permission of the files and deleting `node_modules` in the project directory but none of these steps work.  Thoughts?

Comment: When I have issues with cache in npm, i do execute npm cache verify and then try to npm i once again

Comment: I also get permission denied on npm cache verify ...

Comment: have you tried `sudo npm i`?

Comment: I did not try that because it's not necessary for any of my other repositories, so there must be something wrong with this particular repository.  I also don't want to risk sudo changing file permissions so that I always have to use sudo.

Comment: It can't create a directory there. Does your user have permission to create a directory in that location?

Comment: It should.  I have 100+ projects that I'm running `npm i` for and all of them work except for this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@superflycss/utilities-format

Comment: Also asked on NPM community: https://npm.community/t/npm-i-fails-after-updating-node/7498

Comment: Looks like it's a bug - I deleted package-lock.json and retried it and NPM itself said that it's a bug: https://npm.community/t/an-error-with-npm-itself/7524

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with installing global packages using sudo leaving behind files with the wrong ownership.

The short version is run this to fix the ownership, then try your install again:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm
```

The long version and canonical bug is: https://npm.community/t/global-installs-sudo-npm-i-g-fail-on-mac-after-6-5-upgrade-works-fine-after-6-4-1-downgrade/4082